# GetUIKit Sticky Navbar Changes Background Color When Sticky

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky, getuikit

How can I get my sticky navigation menu to change background color (i.e. blue to white) after sticking to the top of the screen specifically using the GetUIKit framework?

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="uk-navbar-container" uk-navbar data-uk-sticky>
        <div class="uk-navbar-center">
            <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#works" uk-scroll>works</a></li>
                <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#about" uk-scroll>about</a></li>
                <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#resume">resume</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I read something about being active and inactive, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do. I would prefer to only use the GetUIKit framework in this situation, but if there are easy solutions that are compatible with GetUIKit's code, I'd be willing to try! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As written in [docs](https://getuikit.com/docs/navbar#sticky-navbar), you need to provide a class for active state with `cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky`

For valid HTML5 code, I'm using data-uk instead of uk (which works fine as well)

```css
.tall-placeholder {
height: 1000px;
}
.uk-navbar-sticky {
background-color: powderblue!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS & jQuery (not required by UIKit anymore) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<nav class="uk-navbar-container" data-uk-navbar data-uk-sticky="cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky">
    <div class="uk-navbar-center">
        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#works" uk-scroll>works</a></li>
            <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#about" uk-scroll>about</a></li>
            <li class="uk-parent"><a href="#resume">resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<section class="tall-placeholder"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using prefect, You just don't need to revise code, It's already adding a "uk-active " class when you scroll. So place background color on .uk-active class.